# ReactNative fetch doesn't complete until I click on the IOS simulator

Tags: javascript, xcode, reactjs, react-native, redux-thunk

I have a RN component that fires `fetchPosts` in `componentDidMount`.  The fetch posts fires immediately, but doesn't complete until I click on the IOS simulator. If I don't click on the simulator, I'll never see the `receivePosts` action no matter how long I wait.

## Posts actions

```
const fetchPosts = (endpoint) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  dispatch({type: types.FETCH_POSTS, endpoint,})
  const token = getState().user.token
  const client = new RedditClient(token)
  const response = await client.fetchAll()
  const posts = response.data.children
  dispatch(receivePosts(posts))
}

const receivePosts = (posts) => ({
  type: types.RECEIVE_POSTS,
  posts,
})
```

Comment: how were you able to fix this? I experience the same problem.

Comment: Might check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44867336/react-native-fetch-does-not-render-response-until-after-clicking-screen