# Apollo Client will not re-render component on GraphQl response

Tags: react-native, react-apollo, apollo-client

I'm using Apollo Client and React-Native and the issue I'm having is I have a working query making a request when the view is rendered with default data.

- I can see an number in my view which is defaulted to `0`.
- I can see the request being logged on my graphql server.
- The view does not update automatically with the new prop values from the response
- If I touch the screen the view updates and the page is populated with data from graphql.

What is happening here? How can I make it so that when the response comes back it automatically updates the component props and re-renders the component?

Comment: It sounds more like a React Native issue than an Apollo one. Possibly the same issue as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44867336/react-native-fetch-does-not-render-response-until-after-clicking-screen)?

Answer (score 1):

It seems this issue only occurs when the JS Debugger is enabled (the one that opens a tunnel to your desktop chrome). If it's disabled the app works as expected.