# Rendering data, fetched from an API in react-native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, react-native

I am using React-Native and am having issues just getting data to render from an API, into the `render` function. I'm running node JS and express on one end to pull some data from a SQL database. This returns JSON that looks like this:

```
{"routines":[{"routine_id":1,"name":"Morning Routine","start_time":"2020-03-09T14:24:38.000Z","end_time":"2020-03-09T15:24:44.000Z","is_approved":0}]}
```

I want to loop through the `routines` key and print out each `routine` as components in React. I don't really care about what type of component that gets used, I just want to get the data. I've tried a few methods:

Method 1: Using `componentDidMount` with `fetch`:

```
 constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { routines: {} }
}

componentDidMount() {
    fetch('http://localhost:3000/routines')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((responseJson) => {
        return responseJson;
    })
    .then( routines  => {
        this.setState({routines: routines});

    })
    .catch( error => {
        console.error(error);
    });
}


render() {
    console.log(this.state)
```

`render` of `this.state` logs an empty object, despite the `then(routines` portion of the code returning the correct data.

Method 2: Putting everything in `componentDidMount`

```
  async componentDidMount() {
    const response = await fetch("http://localhost:3000/routines")
    const json = await response.json()
    console.log('json');
    console.log(json);
    const routines = json.routines
    this.setState({routines})
}
```

Again, logging the state in `render` produces nothing while logging the json that gets returned from `componentDidMount` does return valid data.

Inside the `render` method i've also tried:

```
const { routines } = this.state;
```

And `routines` comes up as undefined.

Method 3: Directly calling a function to set the state.

```
constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = { routines: this.fetchData() }
    }
```

This ends up returning some weird data:

```
{"routines": {"_40": 0, "_55": null, "_65": 0, "_72": null}}
```

I'm assuming it's because react native does not want me to do this.

I just want a simple way to fetch data from an API and display that data in `render`. I've gone through about four tutorials and all of them end up with undefined or objects set as the default value in the constructor in the `render` method. Am I going crazy? It feels like this is somehow impossible..?

Comment: this.setState({routines}, () => console.log(this.state));
what does it show?

Comment: can you put your code in codepen or jsfiddle?

Comment: its because you are trying to use routines before its loaded by fetch call

Comment: @JatinParmar what would you use to fetch data then?

Answer (score 2):

You do everything right, just use state in `render` and you will see updates.

```js
constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { routines: [] }
}

render() {
    const { routines } = this.state

    return (
        <View>
            {routines.map(item => <Text>{item.name}</Text>)}
        </View>
    )
}
```

Comment: This results in an undefined object, which crashes the code. Probably because routines hasn't loaded yet.

Comment: No crashes, `routines` should be an array. Check routines before setState `this.setState({ routines: routines || [] });`

Answer (score 0):

Since fetch is an async task the data `this.setState({routines})` get's set after `render()` is executed. You can execute `this.forceUpdate()` after setting `this.setState({routines})`. This will re-execute `render()` when the data is set.

See: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate

[However, debugging mode can also be the culprit.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44867336/react-native-fetch-does-not-render-response-until-after-clicking-screen)

Answer (score 0):

its may be because fetch call is async ,and your render method may try to use it before its loaded by the api call,
so your componentDidMount should be like

```
 componentDidMount() {
 this.setState({routines:null})
//fire an api call
fetch('http://localhost:3000/routines')
.then((response) => response.json())
.then((responseJson) => {

    return responseJson;
})
.then( routines  => {
    this.setState({routines: routines});

})
.catch( error => {
    console.error(error);
});
```

}

now inside your render function you should first confirm that routines is not null and have some valid values like

```
render(){
 if(this.state.routines !==null){
   //your code to render component
 }else{
   //your loading or error message
  }
}
```

Comment: What's strange is when I render routines through mapping, I still get undefined objects, because this.state.routines has a default array value.

Comment: can you provide some fiddle, i would like to help you

Comment: After trying this again, render is only called once. It doesn't appear to re-try after the state is set and logged. Not sure how to provide a fiddle with a database :(

Comment: in feedle no need to have data base just replace api call with static api call